# Rails scope with array for where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following scope:

`scope :task_based, ->(dept, number){ joins(:task).where('tasks.department = ? and tasks.number = ?', dept, number)}`

Which works great, except occasionally I need to say something to the effect of `where tasks.number is equal to 123 OR 456`

I know ActiveRecord lets me do `where(number: [123, 456])` but since this is a `JOIN`, that doesn't seem to work.

So how could I pass an array on that scope? It won't always be an array, but needs to account for when it is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do :

```
scope :task_based, ->(dept, number){ joins(:task).where('tasks.department = ? and tasks.number in (?)', dept, number)}
```

The above scope would work on both cases i.e., number as integer or an array of integers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bust out some duck typing for this one

```
                                   # I like to use do/end for multi-line blocks, but that is purely a stylistic choice
scope :task_based, ->(dept, number) do 

  return joins(:task).where('tasks.department = ? AND tasks.number IN ?', dept, number) if number.is_a? Array

  return joins(:task).where('tasks.department = ? and tasks.number = ?', dept, number) if number.is_a?

end
```